# Django cannot retrieve url parameter

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to retrieve a url parameter as part of a simple query within Django but calling kwargs from within the view.py seems to return an empty value (e.g. self.kwargs[name] returns a blank/empty value), it seems Im not picking up the 'name' parameter from the url?

Im pretty new to Django so expect I'm doing something dumb?

I'm using the following url: 
myIpAddress:8000/contacts/search_name/?name=gordon

my code:

URL pattern - works fine.

```
urlpatterns = [

  url(r'^contacts/$', ContactList.as_view()),
  url(r'^contacts/search_name/(?P<name>\w{0,50})$', ContactDetail.as_view()),

]
```

view:

```
class ContactDetail(generics.ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = ContactSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

        return Contact.objects.filter(name=self.kwargs['name'])
```

Comment: Show a sample url

Comment: try def get_queryset(self ,name) and Contact.objects.filter(name=name)

Comment: Just updated question with the URL I'm trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's the best way but I managed to grab the URL parameter using: 
**self.request.GET.get('name')**

This returns the parameter supplied within the url.